# Shear tool in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: node-editor

Is it possible to do a geometry operation similar to the "Shear" tool in Geometry Nodes?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  A shear is pretty simple.  It moves verts in one axis, proportional to how far they lie against another (perpendicular) axis.

This is easiest if we pick object axes for these two axes.  I'll use object X and Y:

[image]

We multiply our X location by some constant (0.5 here) and apply that to the Z location of our vertices.